# How to call the unity of both successful and unsuccessful deals?

Tags: word-choice

On my site users can make deals. If money transferred to seller and product transferred to buyer it's a successful deal(closed won deal). But if money transferred to the seller, but buyer didn't receive the product, and than the money is transferred back to buyer it's an unsuccessful deal(closed lost deal).

By "deals" on my site I call deals with all possible statuses.

"deals" = "closed won deal" + "closed lost deal" + "draft" + "arbitrage" + "in process".

And I want to find out how to call unity of "closed won deal" + "closed lost deal"?

Comment: Deal or no deal, they are both "deals." Just call them that. Note that nothing can be a deal without having ended.

Comment: The problem is that there a lot of other statuses on this site like for example:"in process", "arbitrage", "draft" and etc. So "deals" on this site means all kinds of deals, including successful and unsuccessful too. I need exact word to differentiate "successful" + "unsuccessful" from "successful" + "unsuccessful" + "draft" + "arbitrage" + "in process".

Comment: You can only use "deal" for a "mutually advantageous transaction"; not for others. (http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/deal.html)

Comment: But there exists closed won deal and closed lost deal, they are both deals, but that have ended in different results.(https://marketingdailyadvisor.blr.com/sales/understanding-sales-deal-stages/)

Comment: Trades, exchanges, transactions etc.?

Comment: @user22542 All those words mean all kinds of deals, not exactly "closed won deal" + "closed lost deal".

Comment: Resolved deals?

Comment: Closed, open, lost etc.?

Comment: Sorry, your terminology suggests bidding, not merely consummation of a deal. If that is the case, then....?

Comment: @user22542 "closed" is used for successful deals, "open" is used for deal that is still going(participants are still negotiating), "lost" is used for unsuccessful deals. What I need is word for "lost"+"closed". The answer that there no such word in English will suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**Finalized**" or "**concluded**" deals can refer to all successful and unsuccessful deals.  They seem most fitting and they carry a minimum of potential "won vs. lost" confusion.

> Once deals are **finalized** (whether awarded or not), only open deals
>   remain.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/finalized

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/conclude

Answer (score 0):

I would call these ***completed*** deals.  Per the Oxford Dictionaries:

> ***[complete](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/complete)***
>
> **adjective**
>
> 1. Having all the necessary or appropriate parts.
>
>    *‘a complete list of courses offered by the university’*
>      *‘no woman's wardrobe is complete without this pretty top’*
>
>    1.1 Entire; full.
>
>    *‘I only managed one complete term at school’*
>      *‘the complete works of Shakespeare’*
>
>    1.2 (**complete with**) Having (something) as an additional part or feature.
>
>    *‘the house comes complete with gas central heating and double glazing’*
>
>    1.3 *[predicative]* Having run its full course; finished.
>
>    *‘the restoration of the chapel is complete’*

Here are some examples of this usage:

- [Premier League transfers: every completed deal of the summer window 2016](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/football/2016/08/26/premier-league-transfers-every-completed-deal-of-the-summer-wind/)
- [Are You Sure Your Deal is Completed?](https://deal-studio.com/sure-deal-completed/)
- [Sberbank Rossii : and Yandex Completed Deal for Yandex.Market Joint Venture](https://www.marketscreener.com/SBERBANK-ROSSII-PAO-ADR-35108015/news/Sberbank-Rossii-and-Yandex-Completed-Deal-for-Yandex-Market-Joint-Venture-26448843/)

Of course, you could also simply call them ***closed deals*** which would cover both won and lost deals.  (Although, if there is an third option for closed deals, this wouldn't work.)